# How to load qty_avaiable in Pos odoo

Tags: javascript, odoo, pos

[image]I want to load only quantity that exit in only pos's stock location.When I use qty_available, it load all quantity of product .How can I do that?

```html
var ks_models = require('point_of_sale.models');
    var ks_screens = require('point_of_sale.screens');
    var ks_utils = require('ks_pos_low_stock_alert.utils');

    ks_models.load_fields('product.product', ['type', 'qty_available']);
```

How can replace my code for only qty_available for specific location.Can we use self.env['product.product] feature in js file?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to instead of loading `product.product` model `qty_available` field, you load model `stock.quant` with `inventory_quantity` field. Keep in mind that based on product configuration `Lot serial tracking, owner` etc, for same product there can be multiple `stock.quant`. Total quantity would be the sum of those lines `inventory_quantity` value. You will have to use `this.pos.config.location_id` as domain to filter only quantity on the pos stock location. On `load` function you can map that information with `product.product` model data loaded.

```
// models: [{
//  model: [string] the name of the openerp model to load.
//  label: [string] The label displayed during load.
//  fields: [[string]|function] the list of fields to be loaded.
//          Empty Array / Null loads all fields.
//  order:  [[string]|function] the models will be ordered by
//          the provided fields
//  domain: [domain|function] the domain that determines what
//          models need to be loaded. Null loads everything
//  ids:    [[id]|function] the id list of the models that must
//          be loaded. Overrides domain.
//  context: [Dict|function] the openerp context for the model read
//  condition: [function] do not load the models if it evaluates to
//             false.
//  loaded: [function(self,model)] this function is called once the
//          models have been loaded, with the data as second argument
//          if the function returns a promise, the next model will
//          wait until it resolves before loading.
// }]
```

This is the `load_models` function documentation. `domain` have to be filtered by `this.pos.config.location_id` which is the selected Stock location for the POS, `loaded` receives the `data` result so `stock.quant` records for that stock location, you can loop through this records and store `available_qty` using `this.db.product_by_id[record.product_id]. available_qty=record.inventory_quantity`.

Comment: I understand what you say.But I don't know how to map with product.product. Can you wirte sample code?

Comment: What I meant by mapping is, on `stock.quant` model information, you will have `product_id`, you can match that value with `product.product` model information.

Comment: Yes .I know stock.quant has product_id but In js file, I don't know how to write code for mapping.@arryph

Comment: well you have to share what have you done so far and what's the issue you are facing. Or if you are not familiar with required JavaScript knowledge, perhaps you can use this free addon, if it fulfill your requirement.
https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/13.0/bi_pos_stock/

Comment: https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/13.0/pos_product_available/

Comment: I used this module.But this module show all quantity.I want to load only one location quantity.Thanks

Comment: I used this module https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/12.0/ks_pos_low_stock_alert/ .But this module also load all quantity.Can you help me only load location's quantity.Thanks

Comment: modified that free module to get quantity from location, in pos config select Stock Location and load the POS, it should work.

Comment: There is some error in your code.When I click payment and validate got error.Cant make validate.@arryph

Comment: That's the highest level you can provide? Got error? Nice. Anyway, I checked validating Orders and Closing session, Posting entries. No error. Didn't change any code related to order/payment any way, so can't help. Thanks.

Comment: I really thanks for your help. I added error photo.Please check.

Comment: When I checked it, it got error in js/ks_low_stock.js file and function name is  ks_update_qty_on_product.@arryph.Thanks

Comment: I tested with v13 and it was working, so version shouldn't be a problem. I am not facing the error so can't debug the JS, but seems like missing `product_id` problem.

Comment: You can make payment in pos session?@arryph. Why I cant ?I didn't change anything to pos.

Comment: But When I change self.db.qty_by_product_id to self.db.product_by_id in ks_update_qty_on_product function loop, i got no error. But It is correct?Thanks

Comment: I still got the same error.Can you check line 93 in ks_low_stock.js file?Error in this line.

Comment: .It's showed the qty_avaible product if the product is not exit in stock location.If the product exit in stock location,it show the correct quantity of stock.How can I fix it?Thanks